# Is it possible to access localStorage for my Angular app through Gulp?

Tags: gulp, local-storage

I'd like to run a gulp task that populates my app with sample data from localStorage.  It looks like I can't access localStorage from gulp, is this possible/is there another way of doing what I want to do?

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy, but it can be done with a mix of gulp and javascript. You will have to create an javascript page to populate the localstorage. Just keep in mind the localstorage is domain specific (protocol, domain, port).

Here's what you'll have to do:

1. create a gulp task to open a browser tab (make sure it's the same domain as your app)
2. point browser tab to the html page (containing the script) to populate the localstorage

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` is a browser feature. The API itself is only implemented there, and the data is stored in the browser profile alongside cookies, in a browser-specific format, handled by an entirely different Javascript VM.

So no, there's no way to change data specific to a browser session from node.

You could have gulp generate a bit of code to setup localStorage and inject that into your page, so it populates the storage as soon as you load the page, but it's hard to provide a generic response here.